# Remove all "0" values from List<int>

Tags: c#, linq, list, integer

I'm simply looking for a way to remove all values that == 0 in a List(int).

Thanks.

Comment: Look at `List<T>.RemoveAll` perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few options:

Creating a new list based on the original list and filtering out the 0 values:

```
var newList = originalList.Where(i => i != 0).ToList();
```

Modifying the original list:

```
originalList.RemoveAll(i => i == 0);
```

The old-school, painful way (for funsies):

```
for (int i = 0; i < originalList.Length; i++)
{
    if (originalList[i] == 0)
    {
        originalList.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

The really inefficient, traversing the list repeatedly way (don't do this):

```
while (originalList.Remove(0)) { }
```

Comment: That creates a new list rather than removing values from an existing one. It *might* solve the OP's question, but it might not. `RemoveAll` certainly will though...

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet - I have updated with both options.